# Writing a constructor for a Letter counter

Tags: java, constructor, comparable

I need to write this constructor for a client code that will read in a text file and count the number of instances of each letter of the alphabet. When the constructor is run in the client code, it will output the letter and then the number of instances it occurred in the file, example: `"a" occurred 65 times`. I'm having trouble overwriting the toString method as I get `';' expected` as a compiler error every time I try and I've tried several methods I've found on the web. Also, I have no idea what I'm doing with the `toCompare` method. I've looked around the internet and nothing works quite right. Below are the exact instructions for the assignment and what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as always.

> create a class LetterCount that:
>
> 1) stores a single character (a letter) and a count (an integer) in
>   private variables
>
> 2) implements the Comparable interface, thus there must be a
>   compareTo() method which should compare two LetterCount objects by
>   their count values
>
> 3) overrides toString() with a printable representation that shows the
>   letter and the count

```
public class LetterCount implements Comparable<LetterCount> {
        private String letter;
        private int count;

        public LetterCount(String l, int x) {
            letter = l;
            count = x;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Letter" + letter + " occurs "+ count " + times";
        }
         public int compareTo(LetterCount other) {




    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    return "Letter" + letter + " occurs " + count + " times";
```

Missing a + and the variable names are wrong.

```
public int compareTo(LetterCount other) {
    if ( count < other.count )
       return -1;
    else if (count == other.count)
       return 0;
    else
       return 1;
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same compiler error: ';' expected

Comment: @tbusse125 Post that bad line in a comment.  Someone pointed out above, you have a + inside of a string - " + times"

Answer (score 2):

In toString you are returning 'l' and 'x' which are local variables to the constructor. you should use Letter and Count

And also you included + in the string " times".

For compareTo you need to add a getter for count

```
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}


@Override
public int compareTo(LetterCount o) {
    if(count > o.getCount()){
        return 1;
    }else if(count == o.getCount()){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it, thank you. Any thoughts on how I should go about comparing the values?

Answer (score 1):

You  have been attempting to print out `l` and `x` which were the arguments passed to you in the constructor. When you try to use them in `toString` they do not exist *in scope* -- that is, Java can't see them. You should use the instance variables (`letter` and `count`) that you assigned to in the constructor. These are available to all the methods of your class all the time, unlike `l` and `x` which are *local*, and exist only inside the constructor.

Also, you say you want to compare `LetterCount` instances by their counts. The `Integer.compare` function will do that for you. See the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)

```
public class LetterCount implements Comparable<LetterCount>
    {
            private String letter;
            private int count;

            public LetterCount(String l, int x)
            {
                letter = l;
                count = x;
            }

            public String toString()
            {
                return "Letter" + letter + " occurs "+ count +" times";
            }
             public int compareTo(LetterCount other)
             {
                return Integer.compare(this.count, other.count);
             }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return "Letter" + l + " occurs "+ x + " times";
```

You are missing a `+`

As for the compareTo, this is *typically* used to order LetterCount objects. So in your case compare the count values.

Comment: There is no `l` and `x`. The appropriate variables are `letter` and `count`.